# hapi - request payload validation with joi - problem with payload

Tags: hapi

I get in vscode bellow communicate:

Type 'ObjectSchema' is not assignable to type 'RouteOptionsResponseSchema | undefined'.
Property 'artifact' is missing in type 'import("/node_modules/@types/hapi__joi/index").ObjectSchema' but required in type 'import("/node/node_modules/joi/lib/index").ObjectSchema'.ts(2

Bellow my code, how fix it?

```
const usersPlugin = {
  name: "app/users",
  dependencies: ["prisma"],
  register: async function (server: Hapi.Server) {
    // here you can use server.app.prisma
    server.route([
      {
        method: "POST",
        path: "/users",
        handler: registerHandler,
        options: {
          validate: {
            payload: userInputValidator,
          },
        },
      },
    ]);
  },
};
...
const userInputValidator = Joi.object({
  firstName: Joi.string().required(),
  lastName: Joi.string().required(),
  email: Joi.string().email().required(),
  social: Joi.object({
    facebook: Joi.string().optional(),
    twitter: Joi.string().optional(),
    github: Joi.string().optional(),
    website: Joi.string().optional(),
  }).optional(),
});
```

Comment: I got the same error, did you find a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

My issue was solved by replacing

```
import Joi from '@hapi/joi';
```

with:

```
import Joi from 'joi';
```

In your case it could be replacing `require('@hapi/joi');` with `require('joi');`